My home page is intermittently scrambled - any ideas?
I have created a Wordpress site using the block editor and Spectra One theme. It's all working fine but form time to time the home page is scrambled:
Scrambled page:

What it's supposed to look like:

I've seen this on several PCs and also my mobile. It only affects the home page. All other pages are fine. Navigating to another page and back to the home page doesn't help. Clearing the site cache doesn't help. But the act of logging into the site seems to clear the problem.
Because it's intermittent it's very hard to track down. If anyone has any ideas about what could be causing this, I would be eternally grateful.

Well, it looks like your front-end CSS isn't loading. Why that is I couldn't say, probably something to do with your particular theme, but questions relating to third-party themes are out of scope here.

if it was a theme issue, I think that the problem should be at all loads. here it's intermittent then I think the problem can come from the web host.
